# Get Date of Change

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing Dates and Statuses. I wish to get the date that the status changed to the most recent status. Sample data:

```
DATE        STATUS
01/01/2000  P
02/01/2000  A
03/01/2000  C
04/01/2000  A
05/01/2000  A
06/01/2000  A
```

So in this instance the most recent status is A and it changed to this on 04/01/2000. (The 02/01/2000 row should be ignored in this situation)

Any suggestions for how to go about selecting this row?

Comment: `MAX(Date)` doesn't work for you?

Comment: No. MAX(Date) doesn't do it as that would return 06/01/2000. I want the date where it changed to A.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I misunderstood the question.  You need to get the earliest date of the last status.

You can group sequences of like statuses using a trick -- a difference of row numbers.  The difference (in the query below) is constant for sequences that are the same.  Then you can use aggregation to get the minimum date and select the latest one:

```
select mindate
from (select min(date) as mindate
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum1,
                   row_number() over (partition by status order by date) as seqnum2
            from table t
           ) t
      group by status, (seqnum1 - seqnum2)
      order by mindate desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1
```

EDIT:

In any case, the right way to do this is using `lag()`:

```
select max(date)
from (select t.*, lag(status) over (order by date) as prev_status
      from table t
     ) 
where prev_status <> status or prev_status is null;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1407) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: That gives me 03/01/2000 with the OP's sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using lag or lead.  Here I'm using lead, ordering by date descending to find the previous status date (if it's null I'm just supplying the date, which is needed in case there's only one record).

```
select max(date)
from (
    select status, date, nvl(lead(status) over (order by date desc),date) as previous_status
    from t
    order by date desc
)
where status <> previous_status;
```

Comment: Cheers. LAG and LEAD look very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
with sample_data as (select to_date('01/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'P' status from dual union all
                     select to_date('02/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'A' status from dual union all
                     select to_date('03/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'C' status from dual union all
                     select to_date('04/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'A' status from dual union all
                     select to_date('05/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'A' status from dual union all
                     select to_date('06/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'A' status from dual),
        results1 as (select dt,
                            status,
                            row_number() over (order by dt) - row_number() over (partition by status order by dt) grp
                     from   sample_data),
        results2 as (select status, min(dt) min_dt, grp, max(min(dt)) over () max_min_dt
                     from   results1
                     group by status, grp)
select status, min_dt
from   results2
where  min_dt = max_min_dt;

STATUS MIN_DT    
------ ----------
A      04/01/2000
```